# Why can't ChatGPT access 2023 article links through Java code while poe.com can do that?

Tags: chatgpt

When i used Java code to ask ChatGPT to summarize this 2023 newly written article in 2 lines: https://jamesclear.com/creative-thinking i get the following negative response:

> DEBUG - I'm sorry, but as a text-based AI, I'm unable to directly analyze the content of specific files or access files from external sources. However, if you can provide the text content from the file, I'd be more than happy to analyze and discuss it with you.

While when i use Quora's website ([poe.com](https://poe.com)) and ask the same question using the same ChatGPT model "gpt-3.5-turbo" i get a positive response, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This question might belong to [so] or [genai.se] because it's asking about the capabilities of using an API through a specific programming language, Java.

Answer (score 1):

https://chat.openai.com/ performs some additional filtering. One can use the API directly and it will summarize the article, as poe.com does. One could also use the Azure Playground.

---

Azure Playground:

[image]

---

Azure OpenAI API called via Python: example below.

Output from the Azure OpenAI API:

> The article explores the concept of creative thinking and provides practical suggestions for fostering and enhancing one's creativity. It emphasizes the importance of embracing curiosity, challenging assumptions, and seeking out diverse experiences in order to develop original and innovative ideas. The author also suggests utilizing various techniques such as mind mapping, journaling, and collaboration to stimulate creative thinking. Ultimately, the article emphasizes the potential of creative thinking to enhance problem-solving, decision-making, and overall personal growth.

Code:

```
import openai
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = "https://XXXX.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_version = "2023-07-01-preview"
openai.api_key = "XXXX" 
messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "Please summarize the article s: https://jamesclear.com/creative-thinking"}, {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}]

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            engine="gpt-35-turbo-XXXX",
            model="gpt-35-turbo-0613-XXXX"
            messages=messages
        )


print(response)
```

Output:

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "content_filter_results": {
        "hate": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "self_harm": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "sexual": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "violence": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        }
      },
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "content": "The article explores the concept of creative thinking and provides practical suggestions for fostering and enhancing one's creativity. It emphasizes the importance of embracing curiosity, challenging assumptions, and seeking out diverse experiences in order to develop original and innovative ideas. The author also suggests utilizing various techniques such as mind mapping, journaling, and collaboration to stimulate creative thinking. Ultimately, the article emphasizes the potential of creative thinking to enhance problem-solving, decision-making, and overall personal growth.",
        "role": "assistant"
      }
    }
  ],
  "created": 1690233156,
  "id": "chatcmpl-7fs156sasdcsdvc",
  "model": "gpt-35-turbo",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "prompt_annotations": [
    {
      "content_filter_results": {
        "hate": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "self_harm": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "sexual": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "violence": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        }
      },
      "prompt_index": 0
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 90,
    "prompt_tokens": 32,
    "total_tokens": 122
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! ... Is there a way to execute that through Java code?

Comment: @Brad I haven't tried OpenAI via Java but I'd guess so.

Comment: I found the Azure OpenAI client library for Java, but i couldn't figure out how to use it in my Java project!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/ai-openai-readme?view=azure-java-preview#chat-completions